# Unload static fields

Tags: java, static, initialization

I have a java class that uses complex static fields which need special operations as `close()` so that they are safely cleaned by GC.

For the initialization of static fields I use the `static` block. But I don't now how to unload the static field safely, so that I can call the `close()` method before the field is cleaned up by GC.

Is there any way to unload a static field, similar to the static initialization block?

Comment: Have you considered the use of finalize() ?

Comment: I have. But from what I know, finalize works on objects of class, not on static fields from that class. So, finalize is not an option for me.

Comment: Maybe using a static field that holds the number of active references to objects of that class(incremented in the constructor, decremented in finalize()) AND calling close() or whatever cleanup methods you have on those "complex" statics when finalize() encounters a ref count of 0 after decrementing would do - I haven't tried this, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a way to do what you are asking because the static block gets initialized when the class is loaded and finalize() only works on objects.

Consider replacing your static variables and the complex operation in it with a Singleton class and an instance of it.

This way, you can use a `finalize()` method to perform your `close()` actions.

Comment: finalize is now deprecated. If you need to do something to clean up non-memory resources you'd have to do a shutdown hook, servlet context listener, or other shutdown mechanism your platform supports.

Answer (score 4):

In a web app, you would use a [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

Comment: +1 This is the way to go, IMO. [`contextDestroyed()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)) is called exactly once on undeploy. If necessary, [`contextInitialized()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)) can also be used to explicitly initialize these static fields on deployment, rather than waiting for their particular class to be loaded.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static Uninit cleanup = new Uninit();
....
private static class Uninit { 
    public Uninit() {} 

    public void finalize() {

                     //whatever you need done

    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a neat trick if you want to avoid implementing a singleton. You could even use a private anonymous class. Are there any downsides on this?

Comment: This will only work if the finalizers actually get called.

Comment: Why in the world would you make the Uninit constructor public? (with finalize(), obviously, you have no choice)

Comment: Like Archimedes Trajano said, the finalizer is unsafe because it is not called consistently by the GC. I made this mistake when creating an OpenGL program and had to work everything back again. Just call the `close()` methods after your main loop(or wherever your app uses) to clean up

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a [shutdown hook](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) to accomplish this, but you might not be able to complete all actions. You might have run out of memory or the process might have been killed without it giving a chance to cleanup, etc.

It is better to either make sure your data consistence doesn't depend on this code and/or to move it to code that cleans up regularly during the lifetime of the application.

Comment: `ServletContextListener` is preferable to shutdown hook for web applications. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950396/contextdestroyed-vs-addshutdownhook

Comment: @Kublai, in the context of a servlet container I would agree, the OP doesn't mention the web-app context anywhere in her question however.

Comment: She mentioned it in her comment to Zom-B's answer - agreed that the question should've mentioned that.

Answer (score -2):

No.

Static classes are loaded at runtime when you first use it, and unloaded only when the program exits (afaik).

So you can make a static method `close` in the class itself which cleans up the static members, and call it when you quit.

Comment: And if it is a web application, how do I know when I quit?